# Google sheet cell value to html page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api-javascript-client

I'm doing a little project and I would like to display the top player (Cell A2) of a ranking (sheet: ranking) in an HTML page. My google sheet is shared with everyone.

I found similar questions with several answers. But it seems that each answer is a part of the cake. I can't manage to take everything and simply apply it to my project.

I'm trying to :

- Use the Code.gs file of my google spreadsheet project to return the cell value
- Call the cell value in my index.html file using the  thing
- Display the cell value in a paragraph (p)

What is the easiest way to do that?

Thank you for helping me to find my full cake :)

Comment: An Apps Script Web App can be used.  The Web App can be embedded into an HTML page in an <iframe> tag.  If you want the player to be displayed when the site loads, you can use Templated HTML.  From the Apps Script code editor, choose "Help -> Documentation" and search Templated HTML.